# sarima function with MA(1) structure for the residuals and external regressors

Tags: r

I am running the following code and receiving the following message:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log): 'x' and 'y' lengths
> differ The length of x,y are the same after using the function
> ts.intersect.

Where I am wrong?
To mention that data is for only for 9 years (very few observations). Thank you in advance.

```
ylag1<-lag(y,-1)    
ylag2<-lag(y,-2)    
xlag1<-lag(x,-1)    
xlag2<-lag(x,-2)    
alldata<-ts.intersect(y,x,ylag1,ylag2,xlag1,xlag2)    
model1<-lm(y~ylag1+xlag1,data=alldata)    
adj.model1<-sarima(alldata[,1],0,0,1,xreg=cbind(alldata[,3],alldata[,4]))`
```

Comment: y<-data.frame(volume=c(341,378,356,345,371,395,365,349,379))     x<-data.frame(growth=c(1.2,2.3,1.6,0.8,0.5,1.6,1.3,0.5,2.0))    y<-ts(y$volume,start=2010,end=2018,freq=1)     x<-ts(x$growth,start=2010,end=2018,freq=1)

Comment: Is the model you want to fit valid?

Comment: I have fitted the model with monthly data and it runs smoothly. Data is actually loaded from excel. I cannot figure out why yearly data is a problem since the model converges.